# Spring Batch: Can't quite work out Conditional Flow

Tags: spring, spring-batch

Edited to update my latest configuration: Is this on the right track for my use-case?

I have a flow that's supposed to go like this:

1. The `FileRetrievingTasklet` retrieves a remote file and places the
   "type" of that file in the execution context.
2. If the file is of type "YEARLY", proceed to the `yearlyStep()`.
3. If the file is of type "QUARTERLY", proceed to the `quarterlyStep()`.
4. Finish.

This seems so simple, but what I have doesn't work. The job finishes with `FAILED` after the tasklet step.

Here's my job config:

```
@Bean
public Job fundsDistributionJob() {
    return jobBuilderFactory
            .get("fundsDistributionJob")
            .start(retrieveFileStep(stepBuilderFactory))
            .on("YEARLY").to(yearEndStep())
            .from(retrieveFileStep(stepBuilderFactory))
            .on("QUARTERLY").to(quarterlyStep())
            .end()
            .listener(new FileWorkerJobExecutionListener())
            .build();
}
```

And one of the steps:

```
   @Bean
    public Step quarterlyStep() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("quarterlyStep")
                .<Item, Item>chunk(10)
                .reader(quarterlyReader())
                .processor(processor())
                .writer(writer())
                .listener(new StepItemReadListener())
                .faultTolerant()
                .skipPolicy(new DistSkipPolicy())
                .build();
    }
```

Can someone tell me what's missing?

Comment: `The job finishes with FAILED after the tasklet step.`: What's the reason of the failure? Does your tasklet step finishes successfully? When does the failure happen exactly?

Comment: Yes, the tasklet finishes successfully, but the job ends with "FAILED".

Comment: There is a reason for every failed job, and that reason can be checked with `JobExecution#getFailureExceptions` or `JobExecution#getAllFailureExceptions`. What is the reason of your failed job? Do you have a stack trace?

Comment: The tasklet completes successfully, yes. I was reading that I somehow need to return a "COMPLETED" exit status, so I hacked a different job configuration. I'll edit my answer to reflect it. Can you tell me if I'm on the right track?

Comment: I added an answer with a complete example, please accept it if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach with a decider (before your edit) is the way to go. You just had an issue with your flow definition. Here is an example that works as you described:

```
import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowExecutionStatus;
import org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobExecutionDecider;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.batch.repeat.RepeatStatus;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class MyJob {

    private final JobBuilderFactory jobs;
    private final StepBuilderFactory steps;

    public MyJob(JobBuilderFactory jobs, StepBuilderFactory steps) {
        this.jobs = jobs;
        this.steps = steps;
    }

    @Bean
    public Step retrieveFileStep() {
        return steps.get("retrieveFileStep")
                .tasklet((contribution, chunkContext) -> {
                    System.out.println("Downloading file..");
                    chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution()
                            .getExecutionContext().put("type", Type.YEARLY);
                    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                })
                .build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public JobExecutionDecider fileMapperDecider() {
        return (jobExecution, stepExecution) -> {
            Type type = (Type) stepExecution.getExecutionContext().get("type");
            return new FlowExecutionStatus(type == Type.YEARLY ? "yearly" : "quarterly");
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public Step yearlyStep() {
        return steps.get("yearlyStep")
                .tasklet((contribution, chunkContext) -> {
                    System.out.println("running yearlyStep");
                    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                })
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step quarterlyStep() {
        return steps.get("quarterlyStep")
                .tasklet((contribution, chunkContext) -> {
                    System.out.println("running quarterlyStep");
                    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                })
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job() {
        return jobs.get("job")
                .start(retrieveFileStep())
                .next(fileMapperDecider())
                .from(fileMapperDecider()).on("yearly").to(yearlyStep())
                .from(fileMapperDecider()).on("quarterly").to(quarterlyStep())
                .build()
                .build();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MyJob.class);
        JobLauncher jobLauncher = context.getBean(JobLauncher.class);
        Job job = context.getBean(Job.class);
        jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
    }
    
    enum Type {
        YEARLY, QUARTERLY
    }

}
```

It prints:

```
Downloading file..
running yearlyStep
```

If you change the `type` attribute in the execution context to `Type.QUARTERLY` in `retrieveFileStep`, it prints:

```
Downloading file..
running quarterlyStep
```

Comment: OMG, thanks so much! But I have some questions - One major difference with your implementation is that you define the yearly and quarterly steps as tasklets. Is that what I was missing? I'm not sure how to transform my configuration to a tasklet. I've updated my answer to include one of my steps.

Comment: no it shouldn't matter if the step is a simple tasklet or a chunk-oriented tasklet.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your patience with me... But how does a chunk return a "finished" or "completed" status. It seemed like with my original configuration, that's what was missing, which was why I always got a FAILED status at the end. Or am I still confused?

Comment: Ok, I think I see it working now! I wish I understood this more, but at least it works! Appreciate you much, Mahmoud! Now if you could just help me with this question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64970250/spring-batch-cant-autowire-jobrepository-in-job-listener, I'll be done! :-)